# Mostrar elementos mediante validación de IF

Tags: php, html, condiciones, validación, else

Necesito de vuestra amable ayuda. Estoy intentando realizar un IF con PHP, con una consulta que hago a un mysql. Si la validación del if es correcta, necesito que muestre un select, de lo contrario, una caja de texto, pero no me resulta, ya que me muestra ambos elementos.

Este es el código.

```
  <? if(strpos($resultSol['conductor'], "Si") !== true){ ?>

              <select class="input-text-form" name="nom_conductor" required>
                
                    <?php foreach ($listaConductores as $fila) : ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $fila['grado']; echo" "; echo  $fila['nombres']; echo" ";
                     echo $fila['apellidos'];?>"><?php echo $fila['grado']; echo" "; echo $fila['nombres']; 
                     echo" "; echo $fila['apellidos']; echo" ";  echo $fila['unidad'];?></option>
                     <?php endforeach; ?>   
                    </select>

               <? }else{?>     
              <input class="input-text"  type="text" name="nom_conductor"  id="nom_conductor" value="No necesita asignación de conductor" readonly>  
              <? }?>
```

Pero me muestra ambos elementos

[image: Imagen mostrando select e input]

¿Me podrían indicar mi error?

Comment: Hola. ¿Puedes mostrar cómo creas `$listaConductores`? Si en esa variable **están sólo los datos obtenidos de la consulta**, puedes usarla para verificar si la consulta trajo datos o no. Algo así: `if ($listaConductores) { // aquí construyees el select }  else { //aquí pones el input text }`

Answer (score 1):

Uno de los posibles problemas es que estás usando las [etiquetas abreviadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) de PHP `<? ...?>`. Si [la directiva](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) no está activada en **php.ini**, ignorará la lógica que hay entre ellas (y si es que no lanza algún error de sintaxis). Usar las etiquetas `<?php ...?>`.

El segundo problema es que independiente de que si `$resultSol['conductor']` sea `'Si'` o `'No'`, en ambos casos `strpos()` va a devolver `0` o `false`. Al evaluar esto en el `if`, en cualquier caso, `0 !== true` o `false !== true` va a resultar verdadero, así que entrará siempre a la parte que imprime los `<select>`. Solución, comparar directamente los valores:

```php
if($resultSol['conductor'] == 'Si')
```

Aplicando las mejoras y ordenando un poco el código:

```php
<?php
// ...

if($resultSol['conductor'] == 'Si') {
    ?>
    <select class="input-text-form" name="nom_conductor" required>
        <?php
        foreach ($listaConductores as $fila) {
            $opt = $fila['grado'].' '.$fila['nombres'].' '.$fila['apellidos'];
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $opt;?>"><?php echo $opt.' '.$fila['unidad'];?></option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <?php
} else {
    ?>
    <input class="input-text"  type="text" name="nom_conductor"  id="nom_conductor" value="No necesita asignación de conductor" readonly>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: ¿De dónde sacaste lo de `$resultSol`? No lo veo en el código de la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano estaba mal formateado el código y por eso no se veía, con la edición aprobada ya sale.

Comment: Si, era justamente la etiqueta de php, además cambie mi validación por boleanos y funcionó super!. Muchas gracias